# How to do dependecy in multiple dropdowns that they are in ngFor?

Tags: angular

I have these dropdowns:

```html
<div *ngFor="let filterItem of fields[0].searchParameters;  let i = index" class="custom">
  <label>{{filterItem.fieldlabel}}</label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <span [ngSwitch]="filterItem.fieldtype">
      <input ngDefaultControl [focusOnInit]="i"  *ngSwitchCase="'INPUT'" [ngModel]="selectedDevice" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" class="form-control-full" (change)="changeFilterValue(filterItem.value1)" (keydown)="keyDownFunction($event)"/>
      <select *ngSwitchCase="'LOV'"  class="form-control custom-select" type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterItem.value1" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (change)="changeFilterValue(filterItem)">
        <option value="" ></option>
        <option *ngFor="let value of filterItem.values" [(value)]="value.code" required>{{value.displayName}}</option>
      </select>

      <select *ngSwitchCase="'LOVD'"  class="form-control custom-select" type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterItem.value1" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (change)="changeFilterValue(filterItem)">
        <option value="" ></option>
        <option [hidden]="filterItem.defaultvalue1!=selectedLabel" *ngFor="let value of filterItem.values" [(value)]="value.code" required>{{value.displayName}}</option>
      </select>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

For each of dropdown I have a unique identifier. I have dropdowns of type: user, identifications, town and address.

The problem is: type of identifications depends on type of user, and address depends on town. I don't know how to add that dependency so to tell in `ngFor` that that type of identification depend on type of user. Any suggestion how can I do that?

I don't have access right now to the JSON but it looks like something like this but with rest of data for all dropdowns.

```json
fieds = [
  searchPamereters = [
    {
      fieldType:"typeOfUser",
      defaultvalue1 : 1,
      filedlabel:"Type of user"
      id:1,
      values = [
        {
        code: 100,
        displayName:"Regular"
        },

        {
        code: 200,
        displayName:"Basic"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

I have an API where will I pass these parameters my problem is only how to tell dropdown `typeOfIdentification` that depends on `typeOfUser` and tell address that it depends on town.

Comment: Can you include a sample of what `filterItem` looks like and possibly create [a plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=catalogue)

Comment: in filterItem i can add everything i need, because im getting that from database so i can add columns

Comment: Could you edit your answer to include a sample of the JSON as it is at the moment?

Comment: i posted what i have right now ...i dont have access to full json

Comment: any suggestion how can i do that?

Comment: What do you mean by **"depends on"** do you mean that it must be filled in, or that it changes when the other changes. Or that one should only be shown when the other is selected

Comment: i mean that what ever i change in one that will automaticaly change data on second one. So if i chose code 100 for first one it will display data in second one for that code 100 . I have api for that...where will i pass code and call that data.

Comment: Does [this plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/3dkZBobNDcJ9sCDIslaM?p=preview) do something like what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: what if i have multiple dropdowns how will i handle that? i have for every select same structure because its in ngFor. only data is change So if u put this in <div *ngFor="something of somethings ">  u will get a structure that i have

Comment: [Plunk updated](https://plnkr.co/edit/3dkZBobNDcJ9sCDIslaM?p=preview) is that what you mean? You can edit the plunk yourself and show me what you want that isn't working and I'll fix it

Comment: just one question...how will second dropdown will know on what dropdown will depends?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150748/discussion-between-0mpurdy-and-none).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an object to store the data relevant to each group of dropdowns

**component**

```js
people = ['Alice', 'Bob']
materials = ['glass','wood','metal'];
materialColours = {glass: ['green','blue'], wood: ['brown', 'red'], metal: ['silver', 'gold']};

data = { Alice: {}, Bob: {}} // Object to store the information

constructor() {
  this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  this.materialChange('wood', 'Alice');
  this.materialChange('glass', 'Bob');
}

materialChange(material, person) {
  this.data[person].material = material
  this.getMaterialColours(material)
    .subscribe(newColours => {
      this.data[person].colours = newColours
      console.log('new colours', newColours)
    })
}

// represents API call
getMaterialColours(material) {
  return Observable.of(this.materialColours[material])
}
```

**template**

```html
<div *ngFor="let person of people">
  <h1>{{person}}</h1>
  <div>
    Material
    <select [(ngModel)]="data[person].material" (ngModelChange)="materialChange($event, person)">
      <option *ngFor="let material of materials" [value]="material">{{material}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    Colours
    <select [(ngModel)]="data[person].chosenColour">
      <option *ngFor="let colour of data[person].colours" [value]="colour">{{colour}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Live plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/3dkZBobNDcJ9sCDIslaM?p=preview)